# DXA Failing to Map Images

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-1.5, dxa-net

We have DXA 1.5 running on SDL Tridion 2013 sp-1 and we are running into an issue anytime we try to render images within Articles.  When we attempt to view any articles with images the presentation server gives us the `"A problem occurred while rendering this section"` notice.  This occurs if the images are directly added to the article's *Image* field or if they are embedded within a paragraph's *Media* field.

Articles on the page without images render fine, even if they have an image within the RTF field.

The log file displays the following stack-trace:

> ERROR - Unable to map field 'articleBody' to property of type
>   'Sdl.Web.Common.Models.Paragraph'. Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: Unable
>   to map field 'articleBody' to property of type
>   'Sdl.Web.Common.Models.Paragraph'. ---> System.ArgumentNullException:
>   Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Select[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Func`2 selector)    at
>   DD4T.ContentModel.Field.DD4T.ContentModel.IField.get_EmbeddedValues() 
>   at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.CreateViewModel(MappingData
>   mappingData) in
>   c:\DXA\dxa-web-application-dotnet-annual\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line
>   308    at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.MapEmbeddedFields(IFieldSet
>   embeddedFields, Type modelType, MappingData mapData) in
>   c:\DXA\dxa-web-application-dotnet-annual\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line
>   654    at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.MapFieldValues(IField
>   field, Type modelType, Boolean multival, MappingData mapData) in
>   c:\DXA\dxa-web-application-dotnet-annual\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line
>   517    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.MapFieldValues(IField
>   field, Type modelType, Boolean multival, MappingData mapData) in
>   c:\DXA\dxa-web-application-dotnet-annual\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line
>   563    at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.CreateViewModel(MappingData
>   mappingData) in
>   c:\DXA\dxa-web-application-dotnet-annual\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line
>   310    at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildEntityModel(EntityModel&
>   entityModel, IComponent component, Type baseModelType, Localization
>   localization) in
>   c:\DXA\dxa-web-application-dotnet-annual\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line
>   199    at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildEntityModel(EntityModel&
>   entityModel, IComponentPresentation cp, Localization localization) in
>   c:\DXA\dxa-web-application-dotnet-annual\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line
>   153    at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.ModelBuilderPipeline.CreateEntityModel(IComponentPresentation
>   cp, Localization localization) in
>   c:\DXA\dxa-web-application-dotnet-annual\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\ModelBuilderPipeline.cs:line
>   100    at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildPageModel(PageModel&
>   pageModel, IPage page, IEnumerable`1 includes, Localization
>   localization) in
>   c:\DXA\dxa-web-application-dotnet-annual\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line
>   80

If we remove the images from this article it succeeds.  Any ideas what would cause this kind of error?

Comment: Are you sure this is plain DXA 1.5? The line numbers in the stack trace don't correspond to meaningful lines in the source code: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/1.5/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Mapping/DefaultModelBuilder.cs

Comment: Did you try debugging it and see what error comes in the debug mode and why?

To me it looks the model is not matching somehow with the data returned from the broker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Rick's comment above we looked into our code.  Somehow we pulled the wrong version of DXA (we were working on 1.1) when we added a custom area.  After updating our code base to 1.5 and then adding our new Area, the issue went away.  All versions of DXA are available on Github at https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a similar issue however for that case, the issue was resolved after replacing offending Media Manager images with older images, and then updating/republishing components with the most recent linked images.